# How to declare string with value from other form

Tags: c#, winforms

What I am trying to do is get the value of `uid` from `MainForm` and declare it to `level` in Form1.

MainForm

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SOF_Op_Center
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            error.Visible = false;
        }
        void loginClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (agent.Text == "user" && aid.Text == "pass")
            {
                this.Hide();
                Form1 frm = new Form1();
                frm.Show();
            }
            else if (agent.Text == "user2" && aid.Text == "pass2")
            {
                this.Hide();
                Form1 frm = new Form1();
                frm.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                error.Visible = true;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Form1

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;

namespace SOF_Op_Center
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
            public string server = "server";
            public string user = "user";
            public string pwd = "pass";
         private void Upload(string filename)
        {
            FileInfo fileInf = new FileInfo(filename);
            string uri = "ftp://" + server + "/public_html/data/" + fileInf.Name;
            FtpWebRequest reqFTP;

            // Create FtpWebRequest object from the Uri provided
            reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + server + "/public_html/intel/" + fileInf.Name));

            // Provide the WebPermission Credintials
            reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pwd);

            // By default KeepAlive is true, where the control connection is not closed
            // after a command is executed.
            reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;

            // Specify the command to be executed.
            reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // Specify the data transfer type.
            reqFTP.UseBinary = true;

            // Notify the server about the size of the uploaded file
            reqFTP.ContentLength = fileInf.Length;

            // The buffer size is set to 2kb
            int buffLength = 2048;
            byte[] buff = new byte[buffLength];
            int contentLen;

            // Opens a file stream (System.IO.FileStream) to read the file to be uploaded
            FileStream fs = fileInf.OpenRead();

            try
            {
                // Stream to which the file to be upload is written
                Stream strm = reqFTP.GetRequestStream();

                // Read from the file stream 2kb at a time
                contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);

                // Till Stream content ends
                while (contentLen != 0)
                {
                    // Write Content from the file stream to the FTP Upload Stream
                    strm.Write(buff, 0, contentLen);
                    contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);
                }

                // Close the file stream and the Request Stream
                strm.Close();
                fs.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error uploading data.");
            }
        }
         private void Download(string filePath, string fileName)
        {
            FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
            try
            {
                //filePath = <<The full path where the file is to be created.>>, 
                //fileName = <<Name of the file to be created(Need not be the name of the file on FTP server).>>
                FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(filePath + "\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create);

                reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + server + "/public_html/intel/" + fileName));
                reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
                reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
                reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pwd);
                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
                Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                long cl = response.ContentLength;
                int bufferSize = 2048;
                int readCount;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                while (readCount > 0)
                {
                    outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                    readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                ftpStream.Close();
                outputStream.Close();
                response.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

         public string[] GetFileList()
        {
            string[] downloadFiles;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
            try
            {
                reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + server + "/public_html/intel/"));
                reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
                reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pwd);
                reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
                WebResponse response = reqFTP.GetResponse();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                //MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                while (line != null)
                {
                    result.Append(line);
                    result.Append("\n");
                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                }
                result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf('\n'), 1);
                reader.Close();
                response.Close();
                //MessageBox.Show(response.StatusDescription);
                return result.ToString().Split('\n');
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                downloadFiles = null;
                return downloadFiles;
            }
        }
        void UploadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog opFilDlg = new OpenFileDialog();
                if (opFilDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    Upload(opFilDlg.FileName);
                }
        }
        void DownloadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog fldDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if (txtUpload.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
            {
                if (fldDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    Download(fldDlg.SelectedPath, txtUpload.Text.Trim());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter the File name to download");
            }
        }
        void ShowIntelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] filenames = GetFileList();
            lstFiles.Items.Clear();
                foreach (string filename in filenames)
                {
                  lstFiles.Items.Add(filename);
                }
            }
        }
    }
//}
```

Comment: not quite sure what you are wanting to do?

Comment: MainForm:
string uid = "1"; //send this value to string lvl; in Form1

Comment: To exchange data between forms you can either expose them as properties or communicate them via events.  There are plenty of questions on this site for either - do some more research or make your question more specific.

Comment: @DStanley According to his question he did much research. (But it was edited out by someone else.)

Comment: lol I've been doing research literally all day before asking

Comment: @Jet `lol I've been doing research literally all day` But it seems you miss a topic asked millions of times.... Basically people has many forms and don't know how to use properties and method in other form. Am i wrong?

Comment: @L.B if it's a duplicate, vote to close with a answer that helps him

Comment: @KeithNicholas  Make your search and post the link.... I am busy now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the constructor for `Form1` to take a `string` and then pass `uid` as this value when this in `MainForm`:

#### Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string Level;

    public Form1(string uid)
    {
        Level = uid;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

#### MainForm:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    string uid = "UID";

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    void loginClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var frm = new Form1(uid);
        this.Hide();
        frm.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jet Could you expand on that? In what way is it not working? Do you get an error?

Comment: I think I'm just gonna give up on it. I've been trying everything I could find on this issue all day and nothing works.

Comment: @Jet If you say so - however if you're having trouble in future I would recommend posting a more complete code sample that people trying to answer can replicate exactly, that makes it easier to help you!

Comment: Form1 contains public string uid; and MainForm contains frm.uid = "1"; and the app doesn't run at all. I got rid of the red underlines. And Yes I know, I'm just not quite sure how to explain my problem.

Comment: Now I removed all the code that I placed in order to get this to work, and now my program wont even run.

Comment: @Jet You should consider posting all of the code for your `Form1`

Comment: @Jet I have tested the above code and I think it does what you are asking for - give it a go.

Comment: I tested the code and it semi-works, it just doesn't retrieve the value.

Comment: @Jet What do you mean by that? At which point are you expecting the value and it is not appearing? When I run that code and it reaches the constructor for `Form1` I can see that the `Level` property cointains the value `"UID"`

Comment: Under initialize component I have an if else statement if `uid` is `1` it will tell you that you have admin privileges, if `uid` isn't `1` it will say you have been granted user privileges. After logging in it always says `"You have been granted user privileges"` even though I'm using the log in that grants admin privileges

Comment: The uid is declared under loginClick

Comment: @Jet I don't see that anywhere in the code you posted, so i'm afraid I couldn't possibly tell you what is going wrong.

Comment: THANK YOU BASSIE!!!! You're code worked, took me a while to understand it :) how do I give you rep or something?

Comment: @Jet haha no worries - just mark mine as the answer (click the tick next to the text) and it may help others in future

Comment: Done. Thanks again! Hopefully this does help others.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set variables on form1, do it like

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.level = "whatever";
frm.Show();
```

if level is a bool

then you need to do `frm.level = true; // or false`

or you need to create another property on form1 to hold the information, so you can do something like :-

```
frm.uid = "";
```

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Comment: @Keith Nicholas - I disagree with the downvote as well.  +1'd to countermand that.

Comment: that's saying frm.level is a bool,  you can't put a string in there.

Comment: when someone votes down your answer or question, you won't be able to do that till you get a bit more reputation on the site

Comment: If level is a bool Just create a public boolean Field in Form1

Comment: 'SOF_Op_Center.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'level' and no extension method 'level' accepting a first argument of type 'SOF_Op_Center.Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061

Comment: I added public string level; to Form1 and got rid of all red underlines, but now the app wont run. I'm lost af

Comment: @Jet You were quite close. When you said (above): `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'` - all you needed to do was change the Type of `level` to string. (And what do you mean `won't run`? What happens when you click F5?)

Comment: @ispiro When I hit F5 it builds the solution then that's it. I'm using SharpDevelop. Shortcut keys are the same as VS

Comment: @Jet I don't really know what to say but **maybe** check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/10198352/939213 ?